# How do I make jquery work in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, master-pages

I have read the books, I have googled it to death, but I still get no results. I have an MVC application, and i put the reference to jquery into the master page, as well as the registering the initialization code like so:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
<link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#txt").click(function () {
            var $ctrl = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', name: 'text', value: 'text' }).addClass("text");
        $("#holder").append($ctrl);
    });

});
</script>
```

What that code is meant to do is to add a text box to a div with id "holder" when the button with id "txt" is pressed. I got this code from online somewhere, and it works fine from that page. I can't find it anymore or I would have included the link.
I made the button like this:

```
<input type="button" id="txt" value="Add TextBox" />
<div id="holder"> this is the holder </div>
```

However, when pressing the button absolutely nothing happens. All I wanna know is WHERE DOES THE JQUERY CODE GO? Do i put all the functions in the head of the master page? do i put it in every aspx page? do i put it in a separate file and if so where and how do i reference it? all the books don't make any sense to me, i'm just starting with jquery and this hump is what's stopping me from even starting to get into it. Where does the jquery code go? please help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, the reason your jQuery code isn't getting run is because `~` doesn't make sense to the browser. This needs to either be switched to an absolute reference:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

.. or it needs to be converted into an absolute reference using code that runs server-side:

```
// Using the ascx view engine
<script src="<%: Url.Content("/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
// Using the razor view engine
<script src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Beyond that, you're free to put your jQuery code wherever it makes the most sense. The best strategy I've personally found is to put as much javascript as possible into a static javascript file that gets referenced in the head. In addition to keeping your javascript and markup separated (which just looks a lot nicer), this has the added benefit of putting a lot of static code into a static file which can be cached by the browser, thereby reducing the amount of bytes crossing the wire with each request.

PS: The -vsdoc.js file is purely there for the sake of intellisense, and should not be included in the actual markup. VS.NET will automatically detect its presence and use it when it knows that you're using the corresponding jquery file.

Comment: thank you! your code didn't actually work in my application (I got this error when i ran it "CS1012: Too many characters in character literal", but yeah i realized i had to change the format of the reference so i used this: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> and it worked fine. thanks

Comment: @user858455: Cool, using the google-hosted version is even better. "Too many characters..." message tells me you were using single-quotes instead of double-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/UukmR/1/

It works fine?

Make sure all your script references are correct, and include them in the Head of your master page.

Answer (score -1):

shouldn't your code:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#txt").click(function () {
            var $ctrl = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', name: 'text', value: 'text' }).addClass("text");
        $("#holder").append($ctrl);
    });

});
</script>
```

be contained within the jquery $(document).ready() call?

so try something like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#txt").click(function () {
        var $ctrl = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', name: 'text', value: 'text' }).addClass("text");
        $("#holder").append($ctrl);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: -1 `$(function() {});` is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){});`, so the first code block is equivalent to the second.